# Embedded image in html not displayed from Google App Engine project

Tags: python, html, image, google-app-engine

I want to display some images before a form in an html file that is being served from my handler; I have boiled down to the smallest piece of code down below.

Where do my images need to be stored and what do I need to specify in the `app.yaml` to see them? Currently they aren't displayed, presumably because GAE looks for them in some other location (I have kept the gif images in the root folder).

Here is the code:

```
import webapp2

form="""
<img src="./c1.gif"><img src="./r1.gif">
<form action="/test">
   <input name="q">
   <input type="Submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
      self.response.write(form)

class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
      q = self.request.get("q")
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
      self.response.write("Hello, still not working!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   ('/', MainPage),
   ('/test', TestHandler)
], debug=True)
```

App.yaml:

```
 version: 1
 runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
 - url: /.*
   script: helloworld.app
```

EDIT: Tried the following plus other variations with my app.yaml but no luck:

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /images/*.gif
  static_dir: images
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got your `app.yaml` right, here in [Static file handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) you'll find all the info needed to configure static directory handlers, but it's real simple:

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

Then on html you need to write the full path, starting from root:

```
<img src="/images/c1.gif">
```

And of course this assumes that you have an `images` folder alongside your `app.yaml`, and that it contains said files.

Be sure to read the linked docs, as there are other nuances you should be aware of (like the fact that static directories are served from a cdn outside your instances).

Comment: Thanks @Jaime that was very helpful rather than the pointless thread of comments from the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this.

- You can store it in a static folder and specify it in app.yaml https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles
- Create a handler that server the image from db (and add layer of memcache), this is useful if you're frequently adding image. This way, no need to deploy if you add new image
- Store the image in cloud storage. Serving image through cloud storage won't consume instance hours.

Comment: I did look at the doc link you pasted but I tried a few things based on that but none work. My app.yaml looks like this below and my images are stored in a images folder under root. I also tried a static/images folder but no luck. 
         version: 1
         runtime: python27
         api_version: 1
         threadsafe: true
 
         handlers:
         - url: /*.gif
         static_dir: images
         - url: /.*
         script: helloworld.app

Comment: static folder means static/images and all image references are searched in this folder? Or is it just images/ under the root? I tried both. Where does GA engine look for the image file when it sees img src tag?

Comment: depends on how you requesting it, thats why you specify the handler pattern. What was the issue? can you open the image url directly?

Comment: yes, if I put that code in an html file, everything displays correctly.

Comment: @user3079275 "that" code? so everything works fine now?

Comment: Er no, I meant I can use the embedded html as standalone and the image displays but not as part of the google app engine. My question is very simple: how do I get the snippet of code posted in my question to display the 2 images c1.gif and r1.gif to display when the server is started?

Comment: store it in static folder and specify the folder in app.yaml

Comment: I tried a few things like that as I mentioned in an earlier comment. But no luck. What is the syntax to specify that all gifs are located in a particular folder? If you can point me to the syntax that will be good.